# EasyRTC + Node Webkit: Attempt to connect when already connected to socket server - Error

Tags: node.js, sails.js, node-webkit, easyrtc

I am creating a node webkit application in which I want to implement audio-chat.I have implemented the same with `EasyRTC` and it's working fine. I have a sails server for my application which is running in the port `1337` and the audio-chat that I have implemented is running in `1338`. The problem that I am facing now is that, whenever a user logs in, the connection to my audio-chat controller is established. And when the user logs out, it is disconnected. After the case, if a user logs in again, it is throwing an error:

`Developer error: attempt to connect when already connected to socket server`,
even though I have disconnected the server.

For connecting:

```
$scope.connect = function() {
  easyrtc.enableVideo(false);
  easyrtc.enableVideoReceive(false);
  easyrtc.setRoomOccupantListener($scope.convertListToButtons);
  easyrtc.setSocketUrl(io.sails.chat_url, {
        'connect timeout': 10000,
        'force new connection': true
  });
  easyrtc.initMediaSource(
        function() { // success callback
              easyrtc.connect("easyrtc.audioOnly", $scope.loginSuccess, $scope.loginFailure);
              easyrtc.setUsername($rootScope.currentUser.user.id);                                                                  },
    function(errorCode, errmesg) {
          easyrtc.showError(errorCode, errmesg);
    } // failure callback
  );
}
```

For disconnecting:

```
$scope.disconnect = function() {
     easyrtc.disconnect();
}
```

I ran the application in debug mode, in EasyRTC library file, `self.webSocket` is `undefined` when the user logs out and logs in. Still it's giving the above error.

Can anyone help me figure out what the problem actually is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found any solution??